# Ember controller lookups in separate adapters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In several adapters, I need to modify the urls of a `belongsTo` relationship based on the query params. The original urls are received in a `links` object.

For example, here are my adapters:

```
App.FirstAdapter = App.ActiveModelAdapter.extend
  findBelongsTo: (store, snapshot, url) ->
    controller = store.container.lookup('controller:first')
    url += "?someParam=#{controller.someParam}"
    @_super(store, snapshot, url)

App.SecondAdapter = App.ActiveModelAdapter.extend
  findBelongsTo: (store, snapshot, url) ->
    controller = store.container.lookup('controller:second')
    url += "?someParam=#{controller.someParam}"
    @_super(store, snapshot, url)
```

The problem comes when trying to lookup a controller in two different adapters. I get the error `Uncaught Error: Cannot re-register: store:main, as it has already been looked up.`

I get the above error even if I'm looking up the same controller.

So my question is, is the above a proper way of looking up controller properties in an adapter? And if so, how can I resolve the error I'm getting?

Comment: You're likely running into circular dependency issues in the container. I don't know how to fix that, but I can tell you for sure that using the controller in an adapter like that is a very bad idea. You should be passing any parameters you need through the adapter by using `store.query()` instead of `store.find()`.

Comment: It makes sense not to use the controller like that. However, since I'm getting the relationship and url via a `links` attribute, it seems like Ember is automagically getting the data with `store.find()`. Is there a way I can change that to a `store.query()`?

Comment: The `fileBelongsTo` method is supposed to grab a record for a relationship that exists unconditionally. If you find yourself needing query parameters in order to fetch that relationship, it probably shouldn't be expressed as a belong to relationship. You might want to consider add a computed property or method to your model to perform that logic for you. (Note that these are just comments on your design in the hopes of being helpful. I'm sure there's a way to get your current code working, I just don't know how.)